# Reading a Field's choices via Notes Java API

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have made a small application to extract the values from the Items within a set of Documents, all through the Notes Java API (Notes 7). Many of the Items' type is Dialog list, hence the field values can be one or more of a predefined set of Choices.

I need a way to read the keys/value pairs of the Items' set of (different) Choices, preferably through the Java API as well, but if a more simple solution exist either through the Notes client or the Domino Designer, that's fine by me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type the choices into the form when designing it, then there is no easy way.  However you can design a dialog list field to pull choices either from a view or from a list of fields on a form, perhaps a notes profile form.  Both would be accessible from the API.

Comment: I'm not the creator of the database and yes, the Choices are hardcoded into the Fields. Now you say there is no easy way, but does that mean that there is a way to do it? I mean, it's perfectly accessible information in the Designer, so perhaps I can extract that info from there?

Comment: Yes, the hard way is to use the DXL classes to get at the form.  This site shows an example of how to export a form to DXL:  http://www.lotushints.com/2009/03/custom-web-forms-part-1-exporting-form-into-dxl/

Comment: Sorry for late reply 8-) I extracted the DXL definition file from Notes Designer and programmed (in Java) my way out of the mess that Notes is... at least when not using a real db as backend.